# Error: Cannot find module with yarn start

Tags: windows, yarn-v2

Iv'e changed some files in my project, and then tried to run yarn start, but it failed because of an error  at Function.Module._resolveFilename. The module it can't find was a js file I created. Nothing important was changed. I tried reversing the code, deleting  node_modules and yarn.lock, and running yarn install, and it is still occurring.